# App crashes on OS X Yosemite due to NSOperation (QOS, Quality Of Service)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsoperation, osx-yosemite

My application keeps crashing on OS X Yosemite for the following reason:
Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x608000239d80 :: NSOperation 0x60000013b3a0 (QOS: UTILITY)

Changed my NSOperation to this:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(qualityOfService)]) {
    self.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUtility;
}
```

But application keeps crashing.
Stack trace of crashing thread:

> Thread 7 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x608000239d80 ::
>   NSOperation 0x60000013b3a0 (QOS: UTILITY)
>
> 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff8af4f0dd objc_msgSend +
>   29
>
> 1   com.apple.CoreText                0x00007fff882d0ce7
>   TAttributes::ParseAttributes(__CFDictionary const*, void const*&,
>   TInlineVector, 30ul>&) + 521
>
> 2   com.apple.CoreText                0x00007fff882d06f9
>   TAttributes::TAttributes(__CFDictionary const*) + 257
>
> 3   com.apple.CoreText                0x00007fff882e8295
>   TRunEncoder::Encode(_CTGlyphStorage*, CFRange, unsigned int,
>   __CFDictionary const*) + 85
>
> 4   com.apple.CoreText                0x00007fff882e8231
>   CTRunCreateMutableRunsWithStorageAndOptions + 191
>
> 5   com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0f329e
>   -[NSATSGlyphStorage createCTTypesetter] + 705
>
> 6   com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0ecf0c
>   -[NSATSTypesetter _ctTypesetter] + 324
>
> 7   com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0f78b5
>   -[NSATSLineFragment layoutForStartingGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:minPosition:maxPosition:lineFragmentRect:]
>   + 89
>
> 8   com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0edd43
>   -[NSATSTypesetter _layoutLineFragmentStartingWithGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:atPoint:renderingContext:]
>   + 2901 9   com.apple.UIFoundation         0x00007fff8f0efa08 -[NSATSTypesetter layoutParagraphAtPoint:] + 156
>
> 10  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f040356 -[NSTypesetter
>   _layoutGlyphsInLayoutManager:startingAtGlyphIndex:maxNumberOfLineFragments:maxCharacterIndex:nextGlyphIndex:nextCharacterIndex:]
>   + 4713
>
> 11  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f041ae5 -[NSTypesetter
>   layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:]
>   + 246
>
> 12  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0f0743
>   -[NSATSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:]
>   + 967
>
> 13  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0b9e76
>   -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _fillLayoutHoleForCharacterRange:desiredNumberOfLines:isSoft:] + 1334
>
> 14  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0c370c
>   _NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesForGlyphRange + 1493
>
> 15  com.apple.UIFoundation            0x00007fff8f0c8e54
>   -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:atPoint:] + 542
>
> 16  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8f37fc15 -[NSTextView
>   drawRect:] + 1878
>
> 17  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8f37f409
>   -[NSTextView(NSTextView_LayerBacking) drawLayer:inGraphicsContext:] + 493
>
> 18  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8f332980
>   +[NSGraphicsContext  configureGraphicsContextForCALayer:withCGContext:andRenderWithHandler:]
>   + 97
>
> 19  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e70153
>   CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3306
>
> 20  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6f463
>   ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59
>
> 21  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6f41f
>   x_blame_allocations + 81
>
> 22  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6ef1c
>   CA::Layer::display_() + 1546
>
> 23  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8f31c89f
>   _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 617
>
> 24  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6e641
>   CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 603
>
> 25  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6dd7d
>   CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 35
>
> 26  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6d50e
>   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
>
> 27  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e6d164
>   CA::Transaction::commit() + 390
>
> 28  com.apple.QuartzCore              0x00007fff92e7df55 
>   CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned
>   long, void*) + 71
>
> 29  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff902bdd87 
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>
> 30  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff902bdce0
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
>
> 31  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff902af858
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328
>
> 32  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8d04bab9
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
>
> 33  com.pack.MyApp                0x000000010ab54d5b -[SyncOperation
>   start] + 886
>
> 34  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cfe91a3 __NSOQSchedule_f
>   + 184
>
> 35  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff925e9c13
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>
> 36  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff925ed365
>   _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
>
> 37  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff925eeecc
>   _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
>
> 38  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff925ec6b7
>   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
>
> 39  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff925fafe4
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
>
> 40  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8596d6cb
>   _pthread_wqthread + 729
>
> 41  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8596b4a1 start_wqthread +
>   13

Thank you!